# Use onClick on google maps markers in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I'm actually working on a pokemon GO like game on Android Studio and I would like to assign an onClick listener on google maps markers in kotlin.
I'm working with compose but I don't find the way to add the onClick on my marker.
[Actual code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K35DL.png)

Thank you !

Comment: https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-compose/maps-compose/com.google.maps.android.compose/-marker.html. on click lambda is there. check the docs ``onClick: (Marker) -> Boolean = { false }``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the setOnMarkerClickListener for marker click.

```
    // on below line we are adding click listener for our marker
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener { marker: Marker ->
    
    // on below line we are displaying a toast message on clicking on marker
    Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked location is " + marker.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()     
    
    false
    }
```